# Fatal error on Yii framework page on PHP 8.1

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I just had this error when I updated to PHP 8.1:

```
Fatal Error: Cannot use 'Object' as a class name as it is reserved on line 77
```

I guess it used a reserved word as an actual class. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md) to upgrade.
For example, to use php 7, 8, you must follow the instructions in [this section](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-2012).

```
For compatibiliy with PHP 7.2 which does not allow classes to be named Object anymore, we needed to rename yii\base\Object to yii\base\BaseObject.
```

This also applies to php 8.

**Upgrade from Yii 2.0.12**
If you want to upgrade PHP to version 7.2 in your project you need to remove all cases that extend `yii\base\Object` and extend from `yii\base\BaseObject` instead:

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends where exactly the error occurs.

**Error is in file that belongs to Yii framework itself**

You have to upgrade framework to newer version. Version 2.0.13 introduced `yii\base\BaseObject` as base class instead of `yii\base\Object`.

**Error is in some 3rd party library**

You have to look for upgrade of that library.

**Error is in class that belongs directly to your application**

That probably means that your class extends `yii\base\Object`. You have to modify classes like that to extend `yii\base\BaseObject` instead. This requires the version of Yii framework to be at least 2.0.13. But because the error didn't occur in framework its version should be probably ok.